# How can I push data to the device?

Tags: java, android, push, device

I need a way to push data to my device from my web server, how can I accomplish this? And I would love a guide to help me. I've been stuck on C2DM forever and its just too much for me to handle. The guides are just all list lines after lines of code and don't explain what they do, which sucks. I'd love if you could link me to a guide that can teaches how to push data to the android device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that there isn't too much documentation about CD2M. For me, the best docs are the Google examples. You can grab them and follow the code to understand how this works. Examples are [here](http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/).

- For the client side (the Android app) you have 3 classes that do the heavy work. You can find them [here](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/#svn/trunk/android/c2dm/com/google/android/c2dm). Use them, copy those classes to your project and then you can subclass `C2DMBaseReceiver` to provide your own implementation (you get a callback when you receive a message, a callback for an error, and so on). Remember to register these things in your Manifest, look at the Manifest in those examples to know how to do it.
- The server side is a lot easier. Basically you first get an auth token from Google, and then you start sending HTTP requests that are the messages that your client will receive.
- If you are planning on using App Engine, then you can find examples of how to implement the server in both examples.
- If you are planning on using .NET for the server, then take a look at [C2DM Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/C2DM-Sharp/).
- Else I'm sure you will find some already implemented library or some examples on how to setup the server.

Comment: When you said "subclass C2DMBaseReceiver", do you mean to copy it into your package and work with that? Because I looked and it seems like a great outline. I had copied the 3 files in to com.google.android.c2dm package aswell. I am using a server with the PHP language, and I so far had no problem getting an auth code while using copy and pasted code, but I really want to see what happens in the Register() functions, so I'll be going slower looking at those examples. I'm not using App Engine as I don't really see the need to, I think it will just confuse me more unless you think I'm wrong.

Comment: You need to copy C2DMBaseReceiver to you project (along with the other files) and then subclass it (meaning you have to create a class that extends C2DMBaseReceiver).

Comment: Ohhh make another file, say "C2DMReceiver" and then public class "C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {}" ? I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog post.  It references many possibilities and is probably just what you are looking for. http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score -1):

Use Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) in .NET 3.5 or greater.